# How do I fix error "C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations?"

Tags: c++

I am on macOS right now, XCode Version 12.5.1.
I've encountered an error I haven't ever seen before, and I've searched all over for solutions however none have made sense.
Here's my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <dlfcn.h>

std::uintptr_t rebase(const std::uintptr_t address, const std::uintptr_t base) {
    return address - base + reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(dlopen(NULL, NULL));
}

typedef void(__cdecl* def_print)(const char*, void*);
def_print r_print = reinterpret_cast<def_print>(rebase(0x0069fa14, 0x0));

r_print("hi", nullptr); // Error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations.
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: *"I've searched all over for solutions however none have made sense."* -- that's strange. I searched this site for `[c++] requires a type specifier for all declarations` and got lots of hits with the same message: [You can't have loose statements in the global scope, you need to put it inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34873730).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [While following a tutorial I'm getting an error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34873606/while-following-a-tutorial-im-getting-an-error-c-requires-a-type-specifier-f)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call functions outside of a method, unless you're initializing globals. You need to put your function call inside a method.

I.e.

```
int main() { 
    r_print("hi", nullptr);
}
```